# How to get Json value from "https://www.scopus.com/author/highchart.uri?authorId=7103216110" Url With HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse In C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on DesktopApplication with C# and I want to read json value from this url inorder to deserialize json file and insert it's data into my database and i can't read json value with StreamReader Class :

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using (Stream responseStream = response2.GetResponseStream())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    jsonValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I've made request on this URL using fiddler and in resoponse is a HTML document not JSON value.

Comment: Please check it in Chrome Browser and you will see the json text value

Comment: Im not log in so I can't see it. If you get JSON in response you can parse it into C# class model for example here http://json2csharp.com/. And next User Newtonsoft to make object from JSON.

Comment: after try for first time you will redirect to login page.after try one more time you will see the json value.but my problem isn't it.i want to get json value from http web crowling

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/9.0.1) this NuGet package can do what you need.